# QUERY SOLUTION is slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have this query :

```
select          
   t1.IMMAGINE as r1 ,
   t1.NOME as r2,
   t1.IMO as r3
from
   FOTO_NAVI.dbo.NAVI as t1 
   INNER JOIN 
   (
       select 
           distinct t3.IMO
       from 
       (
           select 
               I_ID_NAVE,
               D_PREVISTO_ARRIVO,
               I_ID_PORTO               
           from 
               Olbia.dbo.ESTERNALIZZAZIONE_FASCICOLINAVE as tint
           where
               tint.D_EFFETTIVO_ARRIVO IS NULL and
               tint.D_PREVISTO_ARRIVO>GETDATE()-1 AND            
               tint.I_ID_PORTO=42104    
       )as t2
       inner join OLbia.dbo.NAVI as t3      
           on t3.N_ident_seguenziale=t2.I_ID_NAVE
  ) AS T4
      on T4.imo= t1.imo
order by t1.IMO
```

Hi guys, this is just too darn slow, and can you make it faster? Problems with speed I believe with the join between t4 and t1

Comment: SO is in English, please use that langauge!

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server` that are to very different DBMS.

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server that is slow? (Two different products, with a bit different optimizing techniques.)

Comment: what is jQuery doing in this query?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it's only possible to give general ideas:

- Look at query plan and statistics io output. That should tell you where the problem is
- Most likely you're missing an index or few and doing scans on big tables, or you might even have a spool because of that.
- Depending on selectivity, some or all of these probably should be indexed: D_EFFETTIVO_ARRIVO, D_PREVISTO_ARRIVO, I_ID_PORTO
- For the joins, check also indexing for OLbia.dbo.NAVI.N_ident_seguenziale and FOTO_NAVI.dbo.NAVI.imo

If these don't help, either edit this question or ask a new one that contains table structures, indexes, query plan and statistics io output.